# LinkedList not printing the first element in a special case

Tags: recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I am new to recursion concept and while practicing I came across a problem for which I am not able to get a logical reasoning.
For the below code snippet, first element of the link is not getting printed (Assume list has more than one elements).

```
public void foo(ListNode head) {
    foo1(head, head.next);
}

private void foo1(ListNode curr, ListNode nextNode) {
    if (nextNode == null) {
        return;
    }
    curr = nextNode;
    nextNode = curr.next;
    foo1(curr, nextNode);
    System.out.println(curr);
}
```

Now for example if list has 3 elements as 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null, only 3 and 2 are getting printed. foo method made a call with head element which is one so shouldn't it print 1 aslo in the output.
Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
    curr = nextNode;
    ...
    System.out.println(curr);
```

The problem is you set the curr to its successor before you print it.

```java
private void foo1(ListNode curr) {
    if (curr == null)
        return;
    System.out.println(curr);
    foo1(curr.next);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

The reason is, before printing the first element, your code changes the value from the first element to the second element. One more issue also present in your code, when we pass one element, it won't print that one element also. Because consider this you have a node 5 and the next node is null. When you pass this node to `foo1()` method, immediately it reaches the condition `nextNode` is null and it returns, here there is no chance to print the first node 5.

I modified your same code to run perfectly as expected, look below.

```
public void foo(ListNode head) {
foo1(head, head.next);
}

private void foo1(ListNode curr, ListNode nextNode) {
if(curr != null)
  System.out.println(curr);

if (nextNode == null) {
    return;
}
curr = nextNode;
nextNode = curr.next;
foo1(curr, nextNode);
}
```